# After stop camera service, the camera does not work anymore

Tags: android, camera

Is there any way to correctly stop the camera service? This does not seem to work:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}
```

After doing that the camera does not work, even if I use the program that is preinstalled in my handset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera=null;
}
```

This works fine for me. Make sure your `surfaceDestroyed()` method is getting invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the the preview callback you might want to deregister it in your surfaceDestroyed

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
```

mCamera is supposed to be your Camera object